# How to have nested trigger in sql?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, triggers

i have a After insert/update trigger. It should gets a field value (lets call it "CurrentState") from inserted record. check CurrentState value in another table, then find another value for this field and then update the newly added or updated record with this value. so after a record update, the currentstate might be updated several times.
Does SQL support nested update trigger?! actually it doesn't work now, i didn't found any mistake in my code. so i get suspicious about sql support.

here is my code

```
create  TRIGGER [dbo].[ASI_trigBPMIAutomaticState]
   ON  [dbo].[ASI_TblBPMForm]
   AFTER INSERT, Update
AS 
BEGIN

    select @CurrentState  = CurrentState from inserted;
    select @FormID = FormID from inserted;

    DECLARE curflow CURSOR 
    LOCAL SCROLL STATIC
    for select w.WorkflowID
    from ASI_TblBPMWorkflow w
    where  w.FromState = @CurrentState

    OPEN curflow

    FETCH first FROM curflow
    INTO @WorkflowID            
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN       
        select @ToState = StateID
        from TblStates
        where r.ResponseID = @WorkflowID

        if (@ToState  =1)
            breake;

        FETCH next FROM curflow
        INTO @WorkflowID
    END -- While Cursor

    CLOSE curflow
    DEALLOCATE curflow  

    if (@QID > 0)   
    begin   
        update ASI_TblBPMForm
        set CurrentState = @ToState
        where FormID = @FormID
    end;
end
```

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190739.aspx

Comment: You are assuming that this trigger is call **once per row** - this is **NOT** the casein SQL Server. The trigger is called **once per statement**, and if that statement inserts or updates multiple rows, then `Inserted` will contain multiple rows and your `select @CurrentState  = CurrentState from inserted;` will pick one of those rows arbitrarily (and ignore all the others). Also: having a **cursor** inside a trigger is about the **WORST** thing you can do from a performance point of view!

Comment: Assuming your used `sql` (which is only the structured query langauge - nothing more), but you really probably meant `sql-server` (the Microsoft relational database product) - correct? Updated your tags accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does SQL support nested update trigger?!

Yes.

[Create Nested Triggers](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190739.aspx)

> Both DML and DDL triggers are nested when a trigger performs an action
>   that initiates another trigger. These actions can initiate other
>   triggers, and so on. DML and DDL triggers can be nested up to 32
>   levels. You can control whether AFTER triggers can be nested through
>   the nested triggers server configuration option. INSTEAD OF triggers
>   (only DML triggers can be INSTEAD OF triggers) can be nested
>   regardless of this setting.

There are nested triggers and recursive triggers.

```
ALTER DATABASE AdventureWorks2012
   SET RECURSIVE_TRIGGERS ON;
GO
```

[Please take note of @marc_s's comments.] I would strongly suggest you do not use cursors in triggers, and make sure your trigger can handle multiple rows.

Comment: Thank you. " SET RECURSIVE_TRIGGERS ON" this was what exactly i needed. now my trigger works well.